# Different color backgrounds for firefox windows

Tags: firefox, plugins, firefox-extensions

I'd like to organize my firefox windows so that each window has a group of related tabs.

e.g.One for email, one for research, one for task tracking (using our web based task tracking tool)

So that I can see at a glance which window I'm looking at, is there a firefox plugin to change the background on a **per window basis**?

Also, is there any plugin that could keep my tabs in order (i.e. make sure only the right tabs are allowed in the right window)

Comment: Have you tried pressing Ctrl+Shift+E and using the in-built [Panorama/Tab Groups](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-groups-organize-tabs) feature?

Comment: No I hadn't, but that looks incredibly cool!

Answer (score -1):

Firefox Panorama/Tab Groups was removed (1) from Version 45 and similar functionality can be found by adding panorama add on (2) to V45+.  "Allasso's Tab Group Helper"(3) will provide a superior feature set and works with earlier version of Firefox. In TGH order of tabs within tabgroup is maintained when a group is opened. As to multiple window management best to use [TMP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/?src=userprofile) (I use it) or [SM](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/) and keep a saved snapshot just in case Firefox has a tab glitch.

(1): support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-groups-removal

(2): addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-groups-panorama/

(3): addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-groups-helper/?src=userprofile

Comment: This seems like an ad for these add-ons